# How can I make a TypeScript generic class to be constrained only to types that are an array of objects?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to produce an example of a generic class in TypeScript. I have the following generic class called `RecordsProcessor` which I want to be constrained only to types which are an array of objects.

If I send a number to the constructor, TypeScript rightly forbids it.

However, when I send an array of numbers, it wrongly allows this.

How can I get this generic class to be constrained only to types that are an array of objects, e.g. objects that have properties to display?

```
// RECORDS (general)
interface IRecord { }
interface IRecords extends Array<IRecord> { }

// PERSONS (specific)
interface IPerson {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: number
}
interface IPersons extends Array<IPerson> { }

// FLASHCARDS (specific)
interface IFlashcard {
    front: string,
    back: string
}
interface IFlashcards extends Array<IFlashcard> { }

class RecordsProcessor<T extends IRecords> {
    records: T;

    constructor(records: T) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    generateCommaSeparatedValueString(): string {
        let r: string = '';
        this.records.forEach((record) => {
            let count = 1;
            for (const key in record) {
                r += `${record[key]}`;
                if (count === Object.keys(record).length) {
                    r += '\n';
                } else {
                    r += ', ';
                }
                count += 1;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }

}

const employees: IPersons = [
    {
        firstName: 'David',
        lastName: 'Krustchen',
        age: 34
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Melitta',
        lastName: 'Schönbrecher',
        age: 24
    }
]
const employeeProcessor = new RecordsProcessor<IPersons>(employees);
console.log(employeeProcessor.generateCommaSeparatedValueString());

const flashcards: IFlashcards = [
    {
        front: 'lamp',
        back: 'die Lampe'
    },
    {
        front: 'table',
        back: 'der Tisch'
    },
    {
        front: 'computer',
        back: 'der Computer'
    },
    {
        front: 'book',
        back: 'das Book'
    }
]
const flashcardProcessor = new RecordsProcessor<IFlashcards>(flashcards);
console.log(flashcardProcessor.generateCommaSeparatedValueString());

// gives error: number does not satisfy the contraint 'IRecords'
// const numberProcessor = new RecordsProcessor<number>(23);

const numbers: number[] = [1, 5, 3, 6, 7];
const arrayOfNumbersProcessor = new RecordsProcessor<number[]>(numbers); // this should also be forbidden by TypeScript
console.log(arrayOfNumbersProcessor.generateCommaSeparatedValueString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict `IRecord` to `Record<string, any>`:

```js
interface IRecord extends Record<string, any> { }
...
// error
const arrayOfNumbersProcessor = new RecordsProcessor<number[]>(numbers);
```

Also, I guess this is a stylistic choice but I would define your types as follows (you may want to be clear that `IPerson` and `IFlashcard` extend `IRecord`):

```js
// RECORDS (general)
type IRecord = Record<string, any>;
type IRecords = Array<IRecord>;

// PERSONS (specific)
interface IPerson extends IRecord {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: number
}
type IPersons = Array<IPerson>;

// FLASHCARDS (specific)
interface IFlashcard extends IRecord {
    front: string,
    back: string
}
type IFlashcards = Array<IFlashcard>;
```